# Validate batch before run it - SET NOEXEC works only for DML commands

Tags: sql-server

How can I validate a full batch(s) of t-sql ,I tried to use `Set NOEXEC ON`, and it helps only for DML commands, such as `Update, Delete, Insert` etc.'

here is a sample:

```
SET NOEXEC ON
GO
 SELECT dbo.IncorrectFunctionName()
 EXEC IncorrectProcedureName
GO
SET NOEXEC OFF
```

Output:

```
Commands completed successfully
```

and :

```
 SELECT dbo.IncorrectFunctionName()
 GO
 EXEC IncorrectProcedureName
```

Output:

```
Msg 4121, Level 16, State 1, Line 11
Cannot find either column "dbo" or the user-defined function or aggregate "dbo.IncorrectFunctionName", or the name is ambiguous.
Msg 2812, Level 16, State 62, Line 13
Could not find stored procedure 'IncorrectProcedureName'.
```

**EDIT:**
it is not only DML commands.

```
USE  AdventureWorks2014
 SET NOEXEC ON
GO
UPDATE Person.Address SET AddressID=AddressID 
 GO
SET NOEXEC OFF
```

Output:

```
Msg 8102, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
Cannot update identity column 'AddressID'.
```

But:

```
USE  AdventureWorks2014
 SET NOEXEC ON
GO
UPDATE Person.Address2 SET AddressID=AddressID -- table does not exists 
 GO
SET NOEXEC OFF
```

Output:

```
Commands completed successfully.
```

Comment: short answer - no. you did (and will) run into the issue with deferred name resolution. And to be honest, even without deferred name resolution, this type of "checking" is very primitive. Erland has a longer discussion of his idea for improvements in this area [here](http://www.sommarskog.se/strict_checks.html) but it remains a wish.

Comment: You could try `SET PARSEONLY ON`. But that won't catch issues with existant functions/procedures that are referencing missing objects.

Comment: i have tried to use `SET PARSEONLY ON`, the result is worse.

Answer (score 1):

just ask for the estimated execution plan

```
create procedure dbo.procwithnonexistenttable
as
begin
    select *
    from dbo.atablethatdoesnotexist
end
go

SET SHOWPLAN_TEXT ON;
GO <-- this is needed
exec dbo.procwithnonexistenttable
GO
SET SHOWPLAN_TEXT OFF;
GO
```

Comment: ok, i got an error message but procedure runs , i want only to validate. using SET SHOWPLAN_TEXT with NOEXEC does not work.